# Absolute position background 100% of page height

Tags: css, html, absolute

I am having trouble with giving my absolute positioned element a 100% height so it covers the entire page rather than just the screen height.

I am using LESS and this is what I have so far:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

div#top-bar {
    background: #333;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

nav#primary {
    background: #333;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This gives me a `nav#primary` height of 100% but that isn't the page height, it's the screen height.

See this image:
[image: Android image]

I want the background to be the full height of the page, not the screen (so it covers the entire `nav#primary`)

Comment: Once remove `padding-top: 50px;` from `nav#primary` and check.

Comment: It still has a smaller issue (like 20px), I require the padding-top to clear the Top Bar (50px height).

Comment: Give `left: 0` and `right: 0` in `nav#primary`. (remove `left: -100%;`)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS

```
nav#primary {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Okay, now I have a weird overflow issue see image: http://i.imgur.com/PaV4Tby.png

Comment: than try with overflow-y: auto? Your initial problem is that div's height is 100% of the viewport, not auto and overflow defaults to visible. So we must try to add the scrollbar to the div instead of body.

Comment: Okay that puts a different spin on things, I will see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

```
nav#primary {
background-image:url(../images/onlinekhabar.jpg);
        background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless `nav#primary` containing all other content on the page, you can't set it to `height: 100%`. Have you considered using a background image on the `body` element? You can force the image to fill the screen with something like `background-size: cover;`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, many thanks for all your help I wouldn't of done this without you guys.

I've managed to somehow get this working, my first step was to remove the absolute positioning from the `nav#primary` and use `margin-left` rather than the `left` option. I also needed to float left and display inline.

For my content `div#main` I also needed to float left and display inline. This is where for my mobile first approach I `position:absolute` it (so my navigation can overlay it). My small media query `(min-height: 768px)`, set the position back to default (static).

In my jQuery I then needed to add this code to get the min-height to change based on the window height. **(Note: min-height not height)**

```
menu.css('minHeight', (jQuery(window).height() - 50) + 'px');
```

The -50 was to remove my topbar height.

**The results:**

*Mobile:*

[image: Android]

*Tablet:*

[image: Tablet]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set relative position at the body. Try to wrap your nav tag with the container and give relative position.

Something like this.

HTML :

```
<body>
    <header id="topbar"></header>
    <section id="container">
        <nav id="primary"></nav>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

header#top-bar {
    background: #333;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

section#container {
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #333;
}

nav#primary {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```